# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#2>'

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types, linq-expressions

i 'm facing one compile time error like

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#2>'
```

here is my code :

```
var query = Enumerable.Repeat(new
            {
                        Id = default(int),
                        Name = string.Empty,
                        type_id = default(int),
                        Ownername = string.Empty,
                        Ownermob = string.Empty,
                        ContactPerson = string.Empty,
                        ContactPersonmob = string.Empty,
                        Phone = string.Empty,
                        Mobile = string.Empty,
                        Room = string.Empty,
                        Build = string.Empty,
                        Road = string.Empty,
                        Area = string.Empty,
                        City = string.Empty,
                        country_id = default(int?),
                        state_id = default(int?),
                        Email = string.Empty,
                        Remark = string.Empty,
                        UserOFC = default(bool),
                        UserVAT = default(bool),
                        UserINV = default(bool),
                        UserNone = default(bool),
                        Username = string.Empty,
                        Register_Date = default(DateTime)},0).ToList();

                    query = db.Parties.Where(p => p.type_id.Equals(GroupByENTYPE)).OrderByDescending(p => p.Register_Date).Select(p => new
                    {
                        Id = p.Id,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        type_id = p.type_id,
                        Ownername = p.Ownername,
                        Ownermob = p.Ownermob,
                        ContactPerson = p.ContactPerson,
                        ContactPersonmob = p.ContactPersonmob,
                        Phone = p.Phone,
                        Mobile = p.Mobile,
                        Room = p.Room,
                        Build = p.Build,
                        Road = p.Road,
                        Area = p.Area,
                        City = p.City,
                        country_id = p.country_id,
                        state_id = p.state_id,
                        Email = p.Email,
                        Remark = p.Remark,
                        UserOFC = p.UserOFC,
                        UserVAT = p.UserVAT,
                        UserINV = p.UserINV,
                        UserNone = p.UserNone,
                        Username = db.Users.Where(u => u.Ref_no.Equals(p.User_id)).Select(u => u.Username).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Register_Date = p.Register_Date
                    }).FilterForColumn(ColumnName, SearchText).ToList();//here error occurs
                }
```

here for declaring common query part and assigning it at multiple condition. at FilterColumn part compile time error faced. how ever at another page same kind of this declaration not gives any problem.

here i put table schema that gives knowledge :

**----------------------Updated----------------------------------------**

```
Id  int Unchecked
Name    varchar(50) Unchecked
type_id int Unchecked
Ownername   varchar(50) Checked
Ownermob    nchar(10)   Checked
Room    varchar(10) Checked
Build   varchar(50) Checked
Road    text    Checked
Area    text    Checked
City    varchar(50) Checked
Phone   nchar(10)   Checked
Mobile  nchar(10)   Checked
Email   varchar(100)    Checked
ContactPerson   varchar(50) Checked
ContactPersonmob    nchar(10)   Checked
UserOFC bit Checked
UserVAT bit Checked
UserINV bit Checked
UserNone    bit Checked
state_id    int Checked
country_id  int Checked
Remark  text    Checked
Register_Date   smalldatetime   Unchecked
User_id char(14)    Unchecked
```

please help me...

Comment: I strongly suspect that one of your property types is incorrect. We can't tell that without knowing anything about your party type. Look carefully at every single property - or get rid of a bunch of them at a time, until you can get it to compile.

Comment: ya it's char(14) as like string

Comment: @JonSkeet just see my updated question.

Comment: It would be a lot clearer if you'd specify the *CLR* types from the generated model code, i.e. the types of `p.Ownername` etc. After all, that's what the compiler is going to be concerned with.

Comment: so, u want LINQtoSQL classes each properties Type details ??

Comment: Well I'd prefer you to look at each property yourself. You can just hover over each property in your second query, and compare that with the type you're using in your `Enumerable.Range` call...

Comment: ok i got it here all bool field are nullable so, default(bool?).

Comment: thnk u guys i solved it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to see from plain text. Try to use binary search to find incompatible properties. That is to

1. comment out last half properties to see if incompatibilities happen in first half properties.
2. If compiler still report errors, do the same for the first half properties.
3. If compiler doesn't report errors, do the same for the last half properties.

Answer (score 0):

The properties of your anonymous types looks identical, so my best guess is that one of your default types differs from the actual types use when you have an object to use.

I think the best strategy for solving this would be to use the **[Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)**

---

Resources:

- You can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hp1Y9bhail8) nice tutorial.
- [Tutorial + example](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-null-object)

Comment: How does the Null Object pattern help here?

Comment: @sloth Instead of assigning `default(int)` and `String.Empty` he can use a null object and it will make sure that the types are correct. I agree it is not the classic use, but it better than the attempt in the question.

Comment: Very complicated solution.

Comment: You're not talking about using a null object, but simply using a regular class instead of an anonymous type.

Comment: @sloth nope, I suggest a null object that will act as the `Party` object in the second query.